# Class Type is showing in top of each PartialView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, partial-views

[image]I have implemented this PartialView in Asp.net Core application named `_SummaryTemplate`

```
@Model Template

<div class="card" style="width:250px; border:2px solid purple; vertical-align:top;">
    <div class="card-title">
        <h4 class="lead col d-flex justify-content-center">@Model.OCCASSION  TEMPLATE</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <img class="col d-flex justify-content-center" style="width:230px;" src="data:image/png;base64, @Model.IMAGE" alt="Red dot" />
        <a asp-page="./Delete" class="btn btn-danger col d-flex justify-content-center">Delete</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have implemented it like this:

```
@foreach(var Template in Model.Templates)
            {
                <partial name="_TemplateSummary" model="Template" />
            }
```

The problem is as shown in image
`GreetingCardGenerator.Core.Template Template` is written on each partial view [I want to remove it] and elements are showing in a single column , I want to show templates in a zig zag manner.

Template.cs

```
 public class Template
    {
        [Key]
        public int TEMPLATE_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string IMAGE { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public OCCASSION OCCASSION { get; set; }

    }
```

OCCASSION.cs

```
 public enum OCCASSION
    {
        
        ANNIVERSERY,
        BIRTHDAY,
        EID
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

View uses ToString() method to show data on the screen. This happens because your @Model.Template  is a complex object that can't be shown on the screen and it's  ToString() method returns

```
GreetingCardGenerator.Core.Template
```

you have to remove from your partial view

```
@Model Template
```

the right syntax is

```
@model Template
```

but since your code is workig , I guess you have this already  somewhere before the line above.

Comment: My Model class is not OCCASSION, It is ```TEMPLATE``` class

Comment: @AsadUllah This is what my answer means, it is a comlicated class inside of Template class. Can you add the Occassion class to your question pls?

Comment: I have added the Template. cs and OCCASSION.cs class